# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of Coefficients for Linear Regression Model

Tags: regression, self-study, maximum-likelihood

I am reading up about using Maximum Likelihood to estimate the parameters of a linear regression equation. I came across this video (https://youtu.be/_-Gnu498s3o) and I thought it explained it very well but it's missing one aspect of the regression equation, the $Y$ intercept $B_0$. In the video he explains that he omitted the intercept for mathematical simplicity which is ironic since it's made it more difficult for me to understand!

In my case I need to determine ML estimates for $B_0$ and $B_1$ for the equation $Y_i=B_1+B_2X_i+E$ where the $E$ is normally distributed around 0 and the S.D = $\sigma$

Would I be right in saying that the video above is the same derivation for my case until the derivative part towards the end?

Not having used the chain rule since leaving school many years ago, would I be correct in assuming the derivative of $(Y_i-B_1-B_2X_i)^2$ w.r.t $B$ is $-2-2X_i(Y_i-B_1-B_2X_i)$ where $B_2$ is Beta subscript 2?

According to my notes I have a different estimation for the coefficients as can be see below, can one enlighten me as to which approach is more appropriate?

Please note that Powerpoint has screwed up some of the locations of the parenthesis.

After doing some more reading I found the original slides where my lecturer got the notes from, unfortunately I can't link to it since I've less than 10 reps. They're from the London School of Economics - Maximum Likelihood of regression coefficients.

Looks like he never inserted the last section regarding the derivative part of ML!

[image]

Comment: I didn't watch the video, but derivation is almost correct, it should be $-2X_i(Y_i - B_1 - B_2X_i)$ (you have an extra -2). And the derivative is with respect to $B_2$